# Can I test that a Sinatra post method successfully saves to a YAML store?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, sinatra, rack-test

I can't find a basic explanation anywhere about how I can test, with Rack::Test, that a Ruby/Sinatra `post` method successfully saves data to a YAML store/file. ([This](http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html) explains testing `get`, which I can do(!), but not `post`; other mentions of testing `post` methods with rack/test seem irrelevant.) For self-study, I'm building a "to do" app in Ruby/Sinatra and I'm trying to use TDD everything and unit test like a good little boy. A requirement I have is: When a user posts a new task, it is saved in the YML store.

I was thinking of testing this either by seeing if a "Task saved" was shown in the response to the user (which of course isn't directly testing the thing itself...but is something I'd *also* like to test):

`assert last_response.body.include?("Task saved")`

or by somehow testing that a test task's description is now in the YML file. I guess I could open up the YML file and look, and then delete it from the YML file, but I'm pretty sure that's not what I'm supposed to do.

I've confirmed `post` does correctly save to a YML file:

```
get('/') do |*user_message|
  # prepare erb messages
  @user_message = session[:message] if session[:message]
  @overlong_description = session[:overlong_description] if
    session[:overlong_description]
  session[:message] = nil # clear message after being used
  session[:overlong_description] = nil # ditto
  @tasks = store.all
  erb :index #, user_message => {:user_message => params[:user_message]}
end

post('/newtask') do
  @task = Task.new(store, params)
  # decide whether to save & prepare user messages
  if @task.complete == true # task is complete!
    @task.message << " " + "Task saved!"
    session[:message] = @task.message # use session[:message] for user messages
    @task.message = ""
    store.save(@task)
  else
    @task.message << " " + "Not saved." # task incomplete
    session[:message] = @task.message # use session[:message] for user messages
    session[:overlong_description] = @task.overlong_description if
      @task.overlong_description
    @task.message = ""
    @task.overlong_description = nil
  end
  redirect '/'
end
```

As you can see, it ends in a redirect...one response I want to test is actually on the slash route, not on the `/newtask` route.

So of course the test doesn't work:

```
  def test_post_newtask
    post('/newtask', params = {"description"=>"Test task 123"})
    # Test that "saved" message for user is in returned page
    assert last_response.body.include?("Task saved") # boooo
  end
```

[Github source here](https://github.com/globewalldesk/todo)

If you can give me advice on a book (chapter, website, blog, etc.) that goes over this in a way accessible to a relative beginner, I'd be most grateful.

Be gentle...I'm very new to testing (and programming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody answered my question and, since I have figured out what the answer is, I thought I would share it here.

First of all, I gather that it shouldn't be necessary to check if the data is actually saved to the YAML store; the main thing is to see if the web page returns the correct result (we assume the database is groovy if so).

The test method I wrote above was correct; it was simply missing the single line `follow_redirect!`. Apparently I didn't realize that I needed to instruct rake/test to follow the redirect.

Part of the problem was that I simply hadn't found the right documentation. [This page](http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html) does give the correct syntax, but doesn't give much detail. [This page](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/Rack/Test/Session#post-instance_method) helped a lot, and [this bit covers redirects](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/Rack/Test/Session#follow_redirect%21-instance_method).

Here's the updated test method:

```
  def test_post_newtask
    post "/newtask", params = {"description" => "Write about quick brown foxes",
      "categories" => "writing823"}
    follow_redirect!
    assert last_response.body.include?("Task saved")
    assert last_response.body.include?("Write about quick brown foxes")
  end
```

(With thanks to the Columbus Ruby Brigade.)