# How to get a Sinatra erb to report back its referring page in params

Tags: ruby, parameters, sinatra, erb

For learning purposes, I am developing [a Ruby/Sinatra "to do list" program](https://github.com/globewalldesk/todo). In `views`, I have the usual `index` page, which lists uncompleted tasks, and also a `completed` page. On both pages (and on many future user-created `categories` pages), there is a similar table, with similar methods for moving and deleting items. These call the same methods, or I'd like them to. But if they call the same methods, at the end of those methods the user is `redirect`ed to the `index` view. But if users are on the `completed` page, they want to stay on that page after deleting an item (or whatever).

To solve this problem, I think what I need to do is pass a variable from the `erb` file to the route block, reporting what view (`erb` file) the user was most recently on. I thought there would be some built-in Sinatra methods to report this, and I looked hard (e.g., I tried [all plausible-sounding ways of accessing the `request` object](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object)), but I couldn't find any. Then I tried using `<input type="hidden" name="pg_type" value="completed">` but for reasons totally mysterious to me, this doesn't work (maybe because [Sinatra uses `type="hidden"` to route `PUT` and `DELETE` requests?](https://gist.github.com/victorwhy/45bb5637cd3e7e879ace)). When I inspect the parameters with `p params`, I see that the `pg_type` param was created, but its content is an empty string (`""`).

An example form from (this is a template used by the other views) `task_table.erb` is this:

```
<form method="post" action="/delete/<%= task.id %>">
  <label for="delete_button">
  <input type="hidden" name="pg_type" value="<% @pg_type %>">
  <button type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button></label>
</form>
```

Here is the route block for that method:

```
post('/delete/:id') do
  store.delete(params[:id].to_i)
  session[:message] << " " + "Deleted task!"
  redirect "/" if params[:pg_type] == "index"
  redirect params[:pg_type]  # But params[:pg_type] always == "" :-(
end
```

So how can a pass info about the referring page from my `erb` pages to my route blocks? Or, if my strategy for solving the problem of returning the user to the correct page is wrong or could be improved (I wouldn't be surprised), please explain.

I'd love to have any more detailed feedback on [this program](https://github.com/globewalldesk/todo). Other problems I'm trying to solve are [how to add unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309462/can-i-test-that-a-sinatra-post-method-successfully-saves-to-a-yaml-store) of `put` and `delete` methods and how to add user accounts (not started with that though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you forgot a '=' before @pg_type:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pg_type" value="<%= @pg_type %>">
```

Comment: God, I _swear_ I tried fiddling with that! But then just now I made that _one_ change in my code and it just started working. Everything was perfect except for that damn little equals sign!